# Oil humidification

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, humidity

I would like to investigate how to increase relative humidity of [transformer oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_oil) experimentally. Firstly, to find out at which rH value saturation occurs and secondly, how long this takes.
So far, however, I lack almost any physical understanding of the processes involved. Can anyone explain to me (in simplified terms) what takes place in order to expose air saturated with moisture (e.g. rH = 80%) to the oil or to have it moistened.
Otherwise I am also very grateful for technical-experimental implementations to humidify oil. So far, best results were gained by using a magnetic stirrer which stirs the oil but maybe there is something better.

Comment: Normally one wants to remove any water from the oil, which we need to do regularly to keep its breakdown voltage near peak...

Comment: Yes, that's correct but I wanna' perform a study on the factors which influence the BDV :) Are you working in the same/this domain?

Comment: Is this your working place? Or what do you mean by that? Btw, do you also have to add something to my question? :)